# What are NHibernate's advantages over other ORM tools?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend), the most popular ORM tool for .Net is NHibernate. However, zero explanations are given. What are the compelling advantages of NHibernate over the other frameworks?

Answer (score 4):

The [NHibernate website](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) makes a pretty good case for itself:

> NHibernate supports transparent
>   persistence, your object classes don't
>   have to follow a restrictive
>   programming model. Persistent classes
>   do not need to implement any interface
>   or inherit from a special base class.
>   This makes it possible to design the
>   business logic using plain .NET (CLR)
>   objects and object-oriented idiom.

For an unbiased comparison of many of the major O/RMs out there for .NET, I would recommend that you visit [ORM BATTLE .NET](http://ormbattle.net/)

Comment: ORM Battle is operated by ORM vendor DataObjects.net: it's not generally considered "unbiased."  At least one major vendor (LLBLGen Pro) has declined to be represented there for exactly this reason, and several others have questioned the validity of the benchmarks.  (Disclosure: I work for an ORM vendor.)  See http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2009/08/15/benchmarks-are-useless-yes-again.aspx for (rather ill-tempered, I'm afraid) discussion.

Comment: It's difficult to prove if it's biased or not, but we did a lot to allow anyone validate the tests (code is publicly shared; there is a Google group managing its further development), so currently they're very good from the point of code. I think it's bad that some vendors rejected staying there - e.g. case with LLBLGen shows that commonly recognized vendor retired immediately after it was shown it is slow in comparison to others. Nearly the same was with NH. So all sides expose _very_ biased view there. I can add players showing fine results there (BLToolkit, Telerik & we) develop it further.

Comment: Btw, almost immediate attempt of NH project lead (Fabio Maula) to "recover" NH results on its own test failed as well: http://ormbattle.net/index.php/blog/105-a-honest-comparison-of-entity-framework-and-nhibernate.html , and this test was truly based on hack.

Comment: Relatively to topic: I'd recommend you to fix the description. ORMBattle compares just LINQ quality and raw ORM parformance on basic operations. Advanced features, etc. aren't compared there - at least currently.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the big feature is [Fluent NHibernate's Automapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) which can take a reasonably complex class model, and create a relational database schema from it.

I'm not aware of any other tool - commercial or open source - that will do this.

Also, extremely powerful and configurable (which can make it arcane, alas).

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of reading available for you to do:

[Advantages and Disadvantages of NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278094/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-nhibernate)

[What differentiates Nhibernate from other ORM’s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658824/what-differentiates-nhibernate-from-other-orms)

And a ton more links to people's opinions on the various .NET ORMs:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

In a nutshell, NHibernate is feature rich and battle tested.  It's free and open source.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend EntitySpaces. it's the best ORM for me, saves me tons of time and money.

I have long time suspected that site, ormbattle is a scam. And as far as i remember, that Yakunin is one of the owners or operator of ormbattle. so take it with a large grain of salt.
check for yourself and don't trust strangers on the net. (except for me, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended at all for critical mission software.
You'll get cryptic generated SQL, and will run crazy to do the silliest of things.

By 2012, big software factories have the explicit instruction of NOT using nHibernate for any projects. It's too risky, too hard to use and too buggy.

Every FAD has its expiration date.